# Make Nextjs to ignore babel.config.js

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, next.js

I Have a nextjs app, I want babel customization to run jest suite for testing, however when I configure babel.config.js file jest runs successfuly, but nextjs is also taking the configuration I dont want that, I want nextjs to ignore babel.config.js, How do I do that?

Comment: I want nextjs to have default babel config that ships with nextjs

Answer (score 11):

Just create a different filename for tests (like `babel.config.test.js`) and make jest use it.

I assume that your jest config inside `package.json`

```
// package.json

{
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "\\.js$": ["babel-jest", { "configFile": "./babel.config.test.js" }]
    }
  }
}
```